# three.js: rotational matrix to place THREE.group along new axis

Tags: matrix, 3d, three.js, rotational-matrices

*(Please also refer to my illustration of the problem:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfwwP.png)

#### problem description and ideas

I am creating several objects in the standard XYZ coordinate system.
Those are added to a *THREE.group*.

Please think of the group as a wall with several frames and image hung on it.
I want to create my frame objects with eg. dimension of *(40, 20, 0.5)*. So I get a rather flat landscape formatted frame/artwork. I create and place several of those. Then I add them to the group, which I wanted to freely rotate in the world along two vectors `start` and `end`.

The problem I am struggling with is how to rotate and position the *group* from a given vector `start` to a give vector `end`.

So far I tried to solve it with a `THREE.Matrix4().lookAt` :

```js
var group = new THREE.Group();
startVec = new THREE.Vector3( 100, 0, -100 );
endVec = new THREE.Vector3( -200, 0, 200 );
matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().lookAt(startVec, endVec, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ));
group.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

var object1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 20, 40), mat);
// etc. -> notice the swapping of X and Z coordinates I have to do.
group.add(object1);

group.applyMatrix(matrix);
```

You can see the example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y6b9Lumw/1/

If you open jsfiddle, you can see that the objects are not placed along the line from `start` to `end`, although I their are placed along the groups internal X-Axis like: `addBox(new THREE.Vector3( i * 30, 0 , 0 ));`

Full code:

```js
<html>
<head>
<title>testing a rotation matrix</title>
 <style>body { margin: 0; } canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% } </style>
</head> <body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.min.js"></script>
<script>

var scene, camera, renderer, light, matrix;
var startVec, endVec;
var boxes;


function addBox(v) {
    var boxmesh;
    var boxgeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 15, 5, 1 );
    var boxmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xdd2222} );
    boxmesh = new THREE.Mesh( boxgeom, boxmaterial );

    //boxmesh.matrix.makeRotationY(Math.PI / 2);
    boxmesh.matrix.setPosition(v);

    boxmesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

    boxes.add(boxmesh);
}
function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setClearColor( 0x222222 );
                    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( -20, 30, 300 );

    var light = new THREE.PointLight (0xCCCCCC, 0.5 );
    scene.add(light);

    startVec = new THREE.Vector3( 100, 0, -100 );
    endVec = new THREE.Vector3( -200, 0, 200 );
    matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().lookAt(startVec, endVec, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ));

    boxes   = new THREE.Group();


    for (var i = -100; i <  100; i++) {
        addBox(new THREE.Vector3( i * 30, 0 , 0 ));
    }

    boxes.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    boxes.applyMatrix(matrix);
    scene.add(boxes);



    var linegeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    linegeometry.vertices.push( startVec, endVec);
    var line = new THREE.Line(linegeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x33eeef}));
    scene.add(line);


    render();
}

function render(){

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
init();



</script>
</body> </html>
```

This works only nicely to some extend. As the look vector is usually oriented along the Z-Axis (i think it is (0,0,1)). So unfortunately the objects inside the group get rotated like that aswell.
This is actually what you would expect from a lookAt() rotational transformation. It's not what I would like to have though, as this places all the children in the group, on *their* Z-Axis, instead of their X-Axis.

In order to have things look properly I had to initialize my groups children with *X* and *Z* swapped.
Instead of:

```
var object1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 40, 20, 0.5 );
```

I have to do:

```
var object1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.5, 20, 40 );
```

same if I want to translate objects in the group on the X-Axis, I have to use the Z-Axis, as that is the look-vector along which the whole wall is oriented by the matrix transformation.

my question is: 
How does my matrix have to be constructed/look like to accomplish what I want: Normally create objects, and then have their X-Axis placed along vector `start` and vector `end`, like placing artworks on a wall, which can be moved around?
I thought about creating a matrix, whose X-Axis is `end.sub(start)`, so the vector from start end end, might this be what I need to do? If so, how would I construct it?

### problem illustration with an image

I tried to illustrate my sitation in two images. One being the *wall*, one being the wall inside the *world*, with the same objects attached to the *wall* (see top of the post).

In the first figure you see the local coordinate system of the *group*, with two added children, one translated along X.
In the second figure, you can see the same localsystem inside the world how I would like it to be. The green axes are the world axes. The `start` and `end` vectors are shown aswell. You can see, both boxes, are properly placed along that line.

Comment: You are missing a fundamental concept about how three.js is designed to work. Instead of manipulating the object matrix directly, you set the object `position`, `rotation` or `quaternion`, and `scale`. The renderer computes the matrix for you. Here is a fiddle to help you set started: http://jsfiddle.net/1wfvL1bt/.

Comment: @WestLangley Usually I use `position`, `rotation` etc. instead of fiddling with the matrix. For some reason I thought it would be better in this case to create a rotation matrix. I stand corrected.
With the help of your code inspiration and the hint to use the standard three.js methods, I will answer my own question shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question by disregarding the idea of manipulating the matrix myself. Thx to @WestLangley I adapted my idea to the following by setting the groups `quaternion` via `.setFromUnitVectors`.
So the rotation is derived from the rotation from the *x-axis* to the direction vector of *start* and *end*, as explained in three.js' documentation:

> "Sets this quaternion to the rotation required to rotate direction vector vFrom to direction vector vTo."
>   (http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion.setFromUnitVectors)

Below is the relevant part of my solution:

```js
// define the starting and ending vector of the wall
start = new THREE.Vector3( -130, -40, 300 );
end = new THREE.Vector3( 60, 20, -100 );

// dir is the direction from start to end, normalized
var dir = new THREE.Vector3().copy(end).sub(start).normalize();

// position wall in the middle of start and end
var middle = new THREE.Vector3().copy(start).lerp(end, 0.5);
wall.position.copy(middle);

// rotate wall by applying rotation from X-Axis to dir
wall.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors( new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), dir );
```

The result can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/L9dmqqvy/1/